# How to make a text box wider using Rails best_in_place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've tried doing this with the following:

```
<%= current_user.first_name %>
<%= current_user.last_name %>
<span class="bubble">
  <%= best_in_place current_user,
        :blurb,
        type: :textarea,
        :cols => "30",
        :rows => "50",
        :inner_class => 'occupation-edit',
        nil: 'Add a short blurb (max 140)'
  %>
</span>
```

However, this isn't working. Is it possible to make the text area longer as in vertical length? It seems like it's not customizable with the 'best_in_place' gem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using [`html_attrs`](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#best_in_place), you can set those types of parameters, like this:

```
<%= best_in_place current_user,
      :blurb,
      :type => :textarea,
      :html_attrs => { :cols => '30', :rows => '50' }
%>
```

And if the `rows` and `cols` attributes don't work, you might want to try the `style` attribute, like this:

```
<%= best_in_place current_user,
      :blurb,
      :type => :textarea,
      :html_attrs => { :style => 'width:500px; height:500px;' }
%>
```

Comment: Thanks @summea that's better however, cols: '30' still isn't making it longer as in vertically. Only rows seems to be working here, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Sonny, both `cols` and `rows` appear to be working in my test app... can you copy/past the exact line of code you are using?

Comment: Sure,    
            <%= best_in_place current_user,
                :blurb,
                :type => :textarea,
                :html_attrs => { cols: '5000', rows: '1' },
                nil: 'Add a short blurb (max 140)' %>

Comment: Thanks; try this: `<%= best_in_place current_user, : blurb, :type => :textarea, :html_attrs => { :cols => '5000', :rows => '1' }, :nil => 'Add a short blurb (max 140)' %>`

Comment: Thanks @summea, still not changing the length of the text area. what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried viewing your app in a different web browser? Maybe there is caching going on... also, sorry for the extra space between `:` and `blurb` in the code I posted in the last comment...

Comment: Np, and yes I've tried that still the same results. Although rows seems to be working, but cols is the important one here.

Comment: In that case, you might want to try using a `style` attribute, instead (answer updated to reflect earlier comment...)